# Why netstandard2.0 shows warning for NUnit3TestAdapter but netstandard1.6 does not?

Tags: .net, frameworks, .net-standard, target-framework, nunittestadapter

NUnit3TestAdapter nuget package shows warning message in reference when target framework is  netstandard2.0 but when project target framework is netstandar1.6 it does not show the warning. I would like to understand the difference in this case.

Warning Message is :

> Package 'NUnit3TestAdapter 3.12.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

I have c# nunit test project where I need to include NUnit3TestAdapter nuget package. I tried to supress the warning but it's not a solution I feel.

my_project.csproj file content

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I expect NUnit3TestAdapter should not show me the warning when netstandard2.0 if it's not showing for netstandard1.6 target framework.

Comment: Hey @ManishaHage - can you add the warning you're seeing to your question?

Comment: @Chris question is updated with warning message.

Comment: https://www.fuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.12.0 Because NuGet expands netcoreapp1.0 for your netstandard1.6 case, but cannot use it for netstandard2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard At last it expands net35 and warns you there might be incompatibilities, which can happen if your .NET Framework installation is older than net461. Overall, it is a bad idea to use netstandardxx in a unit test project. You should use the actual target platforms, like netcoreappxx or netxx.

Comment: @LexLi I understood the meaning of NuGet expands netcoreapp1.0 for your netstandard 1.6 case, but can not use it for netstandard2.0. I saw the word implements in docs.midcrosoft are they talking about interfaces?